# How to maintain background screen at same position when pop up window gets added?

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone app, and I have added a popup control in it, its working fine

Problem: When popup window comes on screen the background screen changes its position and go to bottom.

How to fix this issue? How to maintain position of background screen while using a popup?

Comment: how are you using the popup? I mean could you please share some code with us?

Comment: by using user control

Comment: yes, that's how A popup is used, but where are you making the popup object and putting the user control inside? I mean xaml/c# please share that code too

Comment: Popup popup = new Popup();
                popup.Height = 300;
                popup.Width = 450;
                popup.VerticalOffset = 250;
                popup.HorizontalOffset = 20;
                notLogedInPopup control = new notLogedInPopup();
                popup.Child = control;
                popup.IsOpen = true;